# MediaStore obtain cursor to last recorded video

Tags: android, mediastore

How do I get a cursor to the last video that has been recorded? The purpose is to get a thumbnail. The following code works fine but sometimes it doesn't get the most recent video:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/video/media");
Cursor c = cr.query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
c.moveToLast();
```

Comment: the most recent video is not guaranteed to be a recorded one. Regular videos show up in that list too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DATE_TAKEN` column in your query which will be maximum for the last video. Anyway, as @zapl mentioned in comments, this will not necessarily be a recorded video. Hope this helps.

Comment: in the end I got a reference to the file where the just-recorder video was stored. Thanks for your answer.